# YARN Queue Can't Run More Than One Spark Job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I can run several jobs (MapReduce, Hive) in one queue. But if I run a Spark/Spark Streaming job, every job added after that will be in ACCEPTED state but not RUNNING. Only after I kill the Spark job the other job will be RUNNING.

I tried to create a different queue for Spark and non Spark jobs, they work as expected but this is not what I want.

My questions:
1. Is this YARN or Spark config issue?
2. What is the right config to solve that issue?

Any helps will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You probably need to set your Yarn Cluster to work in [Round-Robin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) mode.